# Unable to add new table using migrate in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

I have created two tables using the migrate command `./yii migrate/create table_name` and `./yii migrate`. Now I need to create new table what I want to use `migrate` command. But it shows error that I have already some tables exists what I created earlier. So, is it possible to create new table using `migrate` command.

Answer (score 1):

If you need create new table with migrate command, you should `./yii migrate/create new)table_name` and in file set your table. You must create new migration all time, if you need create/change table/field.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you want to update a database, creating a new table, modifying an existing or simply entering data to be used for configuration values, you must first create a new migration, so you have to enter in functiion up the code for creating or updating database and in the function down the part for eventual restoration of the situation of the database.